# Crop Image taken by camera without using Bitmap

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an image processing app and I need to divide taken photo into four regions, but using BitmapFactoy takes too much resource and time and slows me down, I would like to do this using raw byte[] data that `public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)` gives me.
Right now this is what I do and I want to improve it to use byte[] to speed it up:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new AsyncImageAnalyzer(data).execute();
            data = null;
        }

public AsyncImageAnalyzer(byte[] d) {
        mData = d;
        surfaceView = null;
    }



 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        FileOutputStream fos2 = null;
        try {

            String fileName = Long.toString(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())+".jpg";
            String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                File file = new File(/*"/sdcard/XXX"*/Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"XXX",
                        fileName);
                /*file.createNewFile();*/
                fos2 = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos2.write(mData,0,mData.length);
                fos2.flush();
                fos2.close();
                /*fos2.write(mData);*/
                /*fos2.close();*/

                if(extrasReceived.equals("1")){
                    spe.putString("FirstPicPath","/"+fileName).commit();
                }else {
                    spe.putString("SecondPicPath","/"+fileName).commit();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ISA exception",e.getMessage() );
        }finally {
            try {
                if (fos2 != null) {
                    fos2.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = sp.getInt("compression_ratio",1);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mData, 0, mData.length,options);
        mData = null;


        t1G = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, (bitmap.getHeight() / 2) - 1, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        t2G = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.getWidth() / 2) - 1, (bitmap.getHeight() / 2) - 1, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        t1R = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
        t2R = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.getWidth() / 2) - 1, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);



        try {
            t2RtoInt = getDominantColor(t2R);
            t1RtoInt = getDominantColor(t1R);
            t1GtoInt = getDominantColor(t1G);
            t2GtoInt = getDominantColor(t2G);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Also any advice for me that causes speed up in these operations would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem lies. I would think that heap space will be a much bigger issue than CPU speed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that commons guy. I know heap space is a problem, yet in future versions heap problem will be solved since I am using bitmaps only for preview right now and they will be removed in the future, but since I need to check every pixle of picture in "getDominantColor(...)" it will be slowed down for good and my first priority is to reduce time by avoiding usage of bitmap.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to crop my image without using Bitmap to speed it up for future processing?

Comment: When you ran Traceview, to determine where your problem lies, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare pretty much nothing I did look at it but it was too comlicated for me I guess. But according to my calculations there is not something else which slows down the app, since when I compress Image the speed of operation is increased in a good manner, the points which problem arises is where I interact with pixles, which is "getDominiantColor()" and also converting raw byte[] to bitmap and again converting bitmap to int[] in "getDominiantColor()"

Comment: @CommonsWare so you don't have any idea how to crop using raw byte[]?

Comment: You can perhaps find some NDK code that takes a `byte[]` of JPEG data and does cropping.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks but I don't think your last comment help me.

Comment: Try implementing custom surfaceview      @override SurfaceViewChanged method and call function Camera.Paramater.setPicureSize(width ,height). This will return smaller image onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever think about [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) (Currently only the JPEG and PNG formats are supported)? If you develop your app with API level 10 and up, you could use this API to speed up the large bitmap processing.

```
    boolean isShareable = false;
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/test.png");
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, isShareable).decodeRegion(rect, options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting byte[] from camera, besides how should I fix the size of Rect ?

Comment: use `BitmapFactory` with `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` to get dimension of your bitmap, then calculate the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot this but my user  actually uses an android 2.3 phone and I MUST support android 2.3 . thanks for your reply but I really need to support Gingerbread.

Comment: @ErfanMowlaei Gingerbread is the the api level 10 (2.3.3~2.3.7), you can use this api in gingerbread.

Comment: @alijandro  Any way to do this cropping stuff without having to provide path of an image, I mean directly from the raw byte[] ?   ( onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera))

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 see the documentation [BitmapRegionDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html), it can handle byte array directly.